# Jpeg wireless transfer with fwrite(); Need to handle lost packets

Tags: c, jpeg, wireless

I am developing a device that takes a picture and transfers that picture to desktop computer receiver wirelessly through radio waves. On the receiver end, I am using C and fwrite() to rebuild the image file sent by split packets of data. Receiving a packet executes:

```
    fwrite(&data[3], size, 1, filename);
```

data[3] is an unsigned 8 bit integer, data type u08.

I confirm that wired file transfer works. If the transmitter and receiver are directly connected, there is no problem.

However, the radio signal is not strong enough to guarantee that all packets will be received. In my testing, lost in transmission packets are common. If even one packet is lost, the image file becomes corrupt. Received rate is roughly 85%.

Every packet is numbered. If the received packet number is greater than the expected packet number, then the receiver knows that a packet has been dropped.

My solution is to loop and replace missing packets with a default packet while incrementing the expected packet number counter. Basically, I plan to fill lost pixels with black pixels, using the received packets to create the most completely picture possible. I do not know how to do this. I tried simply setting data[3] to 0 if the received packet number and expected packet number do not match up, but this did not work.

I welcome other proposed solutions.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, send the file via TCP instead of (apparently) UDP. TCP will handle the retransmission automatically.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to your question.  You should reserve UDP for transmissions that are time-critical, and where a lost packet doesn't catastrophically affect the end result.  Imagine an audio stream, for example.

Comment: I am not using any protocol, neither TCP or UDP. It is true that the transmission style is closer to UDP. Due to the limitations of my project and radio waves, I can only send 128 bits per packet, which I believe is the size of a TCP header itself. I would have no room for the actual data.

Comment: You might need to invent your own protocol to handle things like acknowledgement and retransmission similar in style to TCP. You don't need all of TCP for this, but a simple header containing things like total size sent, size remaining, sequence number (for ACK/retransmission) and maybe some other data. The major part of your package will still be the actual data.

Comment: After further thought, I do believe that using a TCP style transmission can be a good solution to my problem. Like Joachim said however, I would have been invent a smaller protocol. I will try this method out.

Answer (score 2):

U have not mentioned the image format. If you are sending crude RGB image then setting to zero thing should work but if you are playing with compressed images like jpeg and you have lost the header packets having information about block sizes or tables used for entropy encoding there is no way to get the image back.

Comment: My image format is Jpeg. Are you saying that if I store my picture files as .raw, I can implement my original idea to simply replacing lost packets with black pixels?

Comment: In jpeg format information in initial bytes is not about pixels. It tells how to decipher image from the upcoming bytes. If you encode your image as bitmap simple RGB image you can replace the pixels with black ones but the image size will be very large. So go through jpeg compression and as use some predefined quantisation and huffman tables while encoding. On the decoder side just add these in proper jpeg header format in the image.